# Unable to connect to slave from master. "Invalid encoded sequence encountered:"

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have `Box Master` and `Box Slave` in AWS EC2 instances. I created `jenkins` user in `Box Slave` and I copied the `master's` public keys to `slave`. Now I created a new `node` in `Jenkins Master`. However, when I connect to slave using `Launch agent via execution of command on master` using command `ssh -tt jenkins@10.15.0.10`, it gives me the following error:

```
just before slave Services-Slave gets launched ...
executing pre-launch scripts ...
[06/26/17 16:25:28] Launching agent
$ ssh -tt jenkins@10.15.0.10
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1020-aws x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

5 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


Last login: Mon Jun 26 20:19:51 2017 from 10.15.0.5

<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

jenkins@ip-10-94-0-63:~$ <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===ERROR: Unable to launch the agent for Services-Slave
java.io.IOException: Invalid encoded sequence encountered: 08 08 08 08
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1._read(BinarySafeStream.java:194)
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1.read(BinarySafeStream.java:80)
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1.read(BinarySafeStream.java:97)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1._read(BinarySafeStream.java:189)
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1.read(BinarySafeStream.java:125)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1._read(BinarySafeStream.java:189)
    at hudson.remoting.BinarySafeStream$1.read(BinarySafeStream.java:125)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2338)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3092)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2892)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1075)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:684)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:833)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1609)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at hudson.remoting.Capability.read(Capability.java:140)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:391)
    at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:310)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:389)
    at hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:132)
    at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:262)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I run the same command from my `username` from `master` it is able to `ssh` successfully. Any idea why this is happening?

1. I tried giving the .pem file
2. I also did `sudo -u jenkins`. Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Several things were going wrong here too, while configuring master-node communication. Somewhere it seemed like, master is caching the configurations for nodes. Sometimes removing and adding the node did work!

But in the end, this helped every-time.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Qq-EkiUnC5x8BuM4AZWo-yRUQTrkberzz8JfdCM6yuc/edit?pli=1